# trying to connect to node.js and socket.io 0.7.2 from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, node.js, websocket, socket.io

as the question says, i'm trying to connect to the socket.io server from an app running on iphone/ipad.
in another Q i found the link to achieve this with the help of
https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa

... buuuut. it's not working anymore (socket.io 0.7.2).
error messages i get are:

socket.io

```
warn  - unknown transport: "undefined"
```

client

```
Connection failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebSocketErrorDomain error 1.)
```

downgrading socket.io to version 0.6.17 works but i still want to try and get this up and running with the newest version.

maybe someone can point me in the right direction what changed w/ 0.7.2 so i can fix the socketio-cocoa classes (or these https://github.com/erichocean/cocoa-websocket - because socketio-cocoa relies on them).

thx

Comment: just tried the new 0.7.3 - and it's still the same :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i took the time and tried to implement the new [protocol](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) starting with the v.0.7.2.

not everything done yet but there's a rough first draft with which you can work.
rooms are still missing, because i don't need them right now - but feel free to add them yourself ;)

here is the github link [socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc). it's loosely based on the version from [fpotter](https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa) but because i changed some stuff and the two version are *not* compatible, mine got a different name and new repo.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample project?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO 0.6 API & protocol is not compatible with a 0.7 server.

The cocoa classes are still using the 0.6 protocol. The 0.7 protocol specification can be found here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-spec

So the only 2 options you have are:

Downgrading your server to 0.6
Contributing to the third party cacoa project and update it to the 0.7 protocol