# iphone - django : comet

Tags: iphone, django, comet

I'm new to IPhone programming, and also to Django, and trying to send data from django to IPhone right after it was updated by another user.

I suppose comet is the name for it.
Over the internet it's impossible to find a good step-by-step explanation.
can you recommend of provide a good and easy tutorial?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [websockets](http://websocket.org/quantum.html), and especially at websocket.io, that allows you to fall [back to comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436555/html-5-websockets-will-replace-comet) (comet isn't going to disappear anytime soon) when native websockets are not available, although as you are targeting the iphone (app?) you can choose whatever you want.

One advantage of using websocket.io is that it includes fallback mechanisms in case a browser does not support websockets (with flash and/or longpolling)

The current state of afairs in djangoland is, independently of the transport mechanism,  that django and other mainly wsgi based frameworks aren't good at comet/websockets. That doesn't mean you can't integrate comet/websockets with django, but you normally place another piece of technology in between.

A common implementation is to use something like redis+pubsub and a async server combination like node.js/socket.io or a python framework like twisted, orbited, cyclone, or evserver.

Take a look at these questions that have to do with websockets and django:

- [Django/gevent socket.IO with redis pubsub. Where do I put things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678402/django-gevent-socket-io-with-redis-pubsub-where-do-i-put-things)
- [Can I use Socket.IO with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190186/can-i-use-socket-io-with-django)
- [Making moves w/ websockets and python / django ( / twisted? )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363899/making-moves-w-websockets-and-python-django-twisted/4369471#4369471)
- [Django / Comet (Push): Least of all evils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310706/django-comet-push-least-of-all-evils)

some iphone websockets questions I quickly looked up:

- [trying to connect to node.js and socket.io 0.7.2 from iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535155/trying-to-connect-to-node-js-and-socket-io-0-7-2-from-iphone)
- [iPhone Objective-C socket communication with Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951461/iphone-objective-c-socket-communication-with-socket-io)

some tutorials/projects that might help with the django side:

- [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio)
- [evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent](http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/)
- [pycon-sprints-part-1-the-realtime-web-with-gevent](http://sontek.net/pycon-sprints-part-1-the-realtime-web-with-gevent)
- [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: as far as I know comet suppose to be a simpler option.